# What can be done about "Compiler synthesis of Manifest and OptManifest is deprecated"

Tags: json4s

#### json4s version 4.0.3

#### scala version 3.1.0

#### jdk version 1.8.0_181

Does everyone else get warnings like this?  Is there a way to suppress or work around them?

```
[warn] -- Deprecation Warning: ...\serialization\json\JSONSerializer.scala:76:51
[warn] 76 |    val graphs = (json \ "graphs").extract[JObject].obj.map { case (key, json) =>
[warn]    |                                                   ^
[warn]    |Compiler synthesis of Manifest and OptManifest is deprecated, instead
[warn]    |replace with the type `scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.json4s.JObject]`.
[warn]    |Alternatively, consider using the new metaprogramming features of Scala 3,
[warn]    |see https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming.html
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecations are a part of library development and warnings are for the interested parties to either use older versions or make adjustments accordingly.

As for Scala, a year ago, Scala 2.13.2 introduced a compiler flag, `-Wconf`, to configure error/warning levels along with many in-code annotations to use. please visit [configuring-and-suppressing-warnings](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html) for details and more.

In your case, you may simply use the `-Wconf:cat=deprecation:ss` (`ss` for `silent-summary`) where you will get only the total number of deprecation warnings at the end of the process.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been using :ws for warning-summary as described on the page you reference, but it is not valid for Scala 3.  Unfortunately, neither is the :ss that you suggest.

[warn] Failed to parse `-Wconf` configuration: cat=deprecation:ss
[warn] unknown action: `ss`

Comment: @KeithAlcock I had in mind "don't show anything other than in summary" and seems it won't work that way. have you tried a single `i` to ignore them or `s` flag to silence these messages? I think you won't see any deprecation messages with them, so keep that in mind for security concerns.

Comment: @KeithAlcock, alright, I was not prepared enough to see that many languages/frameworks did breaking changes in 2021, and compatibility issues flying all around. I have check their [compiler migration compatibility](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/options-lookup.html) post and they are yet to implement many flags, and not clear if they will. please check the same migration guide or revert to a 2.x version if you are in trial-error phase